# angularjs - testing controller

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am just starting with angular and I wanted to write some simple unit tests for my controllers, here is what I got.

app.js:

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('Prototype', ['setsAndCollectionsService']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', controller: 'DashboardController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/setsAndCollections', {templateUrl: 'partials/setsAndCollections.html', controller: SetsAndCollectionsController});
    $routeProvider.when('/repetition', {templateUrl: 'partials/repetition.html', controller: RepetitionController});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});
  }]);
```

and controllers.js

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

    var myApp = angular.module('Prototype');

    myApp.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', function (scope) {
        scope.repeats = 6;
    }]);

/*function DashboardController($scope) {
 $scope.repeats = 5;
 };*/

function SetsAndCollectionsController($scope, $location, collectionsService, repetitionService) {
    $scope.id = 3;
    $scope.collections = collectionsService.getCollections();
    $scope.selectedCollection;
    $scope.repetitionService = repetitionService;

    $scope.switchCollection = function (collection) {
        $scope.selectedCollection = collection;
    };

    $scope.addCollection = function () {
        $scope.collections.push({
            name: "collection" + $scope.id,
            sets: []
        });
        ++($scope.id);
    };

    $scope.addSet = function () {
        $scope.selectedCollection.sets.push({
            name: "set" + $scope.id,
            questions: []
        });
        ++($scope.id);
    };

    $scope.modifyRepetition = function (set) {
        if (set.isSelected) {
            $scope.repetitionService.removeSet(set);
        } else {
            $scope.repetitionService.addSet(set);
        }

        set.isSelected = !set.isSelected;
    };

    $scope.selectAllSets = function () {
        var selectedCollectionSets = $scope.selectedCollection.sets;

        for (var set in selectedCollectionSets) {
            if (selectedCollectionSets[set].isSelected == false) {
                $scope.repetitionService.addSet(set);
            }
            selectedCollectionSets[set].isSelected = true;
        }
    };

    $scope.deselectAllSets = function () {
        var selectedCollectionSets = $scope.selectedCollection.sets;

        for (var set in selectedCollectionSets) {
            if (selectedCollectionSets[set].isSelected) {
                $scope.repetitionService.removeSet(set);
            }
            selectedCollectionSets[set].isSelected = false;
        }
    };

    $scope.startRepetition = function () {
        $location.path("/repetition");
    };
}

function RepetitionController($scope, $location, repetitionService) {
    $scope.sets = repetitionService.getSets();
    $scope.questionsLeft = $scope.sets.length;
    $scope.questionsAnswered = 0;
    $scope.percentageLeft = ($scope.questionsLeft == 0 ? 100 : 0);

    $scope.endRepetition = function () {
        $location.path("/setsAndCollections");
    };
}
```

now I am in process of converting global function controllers to ones defined by angular API as you can see by example of `DashboardController`.

Now in my test:

```
describe("DashboardController", function () {
    var ctrl, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('DashboardController', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    it("has repeats attribute set to 5", function () {
        expect(scope.repeats).toBe(5);
    });
});
```

I am getting

```
    Error: Argument 'DashboardController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I am wondering then, where is my mistake? If I understand this right, `ctrl = $controller('DashboardController', {$scope: scope});` should inject my newly created scope to my `DashboardController` to populate it with attributes - in this case, `repeats`.

Comment: Are you making sure to include your controllers.js in your test runner?  For example in your karma-runner config file?

Comment: I checked, the file is read OK, what is interesting is, that if I uncomment the global function style of `DashboardController`, this simple test passes so this file should be included.

Comment: For what it's worth you shouldn't be hanging elements off your $scope variable. $scope should contain a REFERENCE to your model, but it's NOT your model. e.g. `$scope.id` should be something like `$scope.SetsAndCollectionsModel.id`. The reason for this comes from issues trying to set primative types from a child scope to a parent scope. You can watch a video that describes this [here](http://www.egghead.io/video/DTx23w4z6Kc). Misko, who created Angular, talks about it in a [best practices](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) video as well (sorry, don't have a link directly to the time)

Comment: Thanks for the video with best practices, will watch it for sure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to set up your Prototype module first.

```
beforeEach(module('Prototype'));
```

Add that to your test, above the current `beforeEach` would work.

```
describe("DashboardController", function () {
  var ctrl, scope;

  beforeEach(module('Prototype'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('DashboardController', {$scope: scope});
  }));

  it("has repeats attribute set to 5", function () {
    expect(scope.repeats).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing fragment.