# Testing Angular Controllers defined like angular.module('myApp').controller(

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I am playing around with https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

A controller is defined in app/controllers.js like this

```
'use strict';
function MyCtrl1() {}
MyCtrl1.$inject = [];
```

this doesn't pass jshint as MyCtrl1 is referenced in app/app.js and not in my globals list.

According to [Brian Ford](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html) and others I have read the preferred style is

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl1', [], function () {});
```

I like this better as it's not in the global scope, but now my testacular specs fail because this doesn't work anymore:

```
var myCtrl1;
beforeEach(function(){
  myCtrl1 = new MyCtrl1();
});
```

How do I get a reference to this controller which is defined in the "preferred" style for testing purposes?

Comment: This might be the same issue that I have anwsered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799853/angularjs-testing-controller/15801116#15801116)  You need to add `beforeEach(module('myApp'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

credit due to both Javito and Xesued:

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
var scope, ctrl;
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl1', {$scope: scope});
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    scope = {};    
    MyCtrl1 = $controller('MyCtrl1', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));
```

Comment: close, it seems you need a real scope, and also the beforeEach as suggested by Xesued in the comments. code is not working out here, I guess I have to answer it myself. Sorry, I wanted to give you the credit :(