# Testing Angular Controllers: Controller Not Defined

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, karma-runner

My question is very similar to [Testing Angular Controllers defined like angular.module('myApp').controller(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869088/testing-angular-controllers-defined-like-angular-modulemyapp-controller). Rather than hijacking that question, I thought I would ask mine separately. when I use the proposed answer of the form:

```
describe('evCalcApp controllers', function(){
  beforeEach(module('evCalcApp.controllers'));
    var scope, ctrl
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('MyMileageCalcController', {$scope: scope});
    }));
```

That works fine for the first controller. However, if you were testing more than one controller in the same file, how would you inject the second controller (let's just call it `MyCtrl2`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way you did the last one

```
describe('evCalcApp controllers', function(){
  beforeEach(module('evCalcApp.controllers'));
    var scope, ctrl, ctrl2;
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      scope2 = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('MyMileageCalcController', {$scope: scope});
      ctrl2 = $controller('MyCtrl2', {$scope: scope2});
    }));
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. So it appears this cannot go inside the `describe` block for the given controller but rather must live inside the outer `describe` for the module. Right?